# object references an unsaved transient instance multiple relations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've some errors in above code the error says

`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references 
an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
crm.venkat.model.Accounts; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved 
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
crm.venkat.model.Accounts`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contacts")
public class Contact {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "jt_accounts_contacts", joinColumns = {     @JoinColumn(name = "contactid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =     "accountid") })
    private Accounts account = new Accounts();

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")
public class Accounts {

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, targetEntity=Contact.class,     mappedBy="account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

It works when I insert contacts with filling accounts. If I don't fill account it gets above error. I want accounts class to be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you create `Accounts` in the field initializer, so if it is not overwritten with a managed `Accounts` instance, Hibernate sees it as transient and throws the exception at flush time.

The solution is not to create it in the field initializer:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "jt_accounts_contacts", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "contactid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "accountid")})
private Accounts account;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Could you send me the link for their documentations?

Comment: @VenkyVenkat [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/) is the official documentation.